# Admin Panel like Custom CMS Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to Create a Framework , like Admin panel , which can rule almost all the aspects of what is shown on the frontend.

For an eg (Most basic one): If suppose the links which are to be shown in a Navigation area is passed from the server, with the order and the url , etc.

The whole aim is to save the time on the tedious tasks. U can just start creating  Menus and start assigning pages to it. Give Url, Actual files which are to be rendered (in case of static files.), In case of dynamic files , giving the file accordingly.
And this is fully server side manageable using different portlets, sort of things.

So basic Roadmap is having :

**Areas like :**

**Header Area -** Which can contain logos , links etc.

**Navigation Area -** Which can contains links and submenus.

**Content Area -** Now this is where the tricky part is that that It has Zones like : Left , Center & Right. It contains Order in which it has to be displayed. So, when someday we want to change the way the articles appear on the page, we can do so easily, without any deployments. Now these Zones , can have n no of internal elements, like the word cloud , or the advertisment area.

**Footer Area :** Again similar as Header Area.

Currently there is a Framework already existing, this is using XSLT files for pulling out data from server sides.
For an eg: If there's a Grid it will be having a  tag embedded in the XSLT file. Now whatever might be the source of the data , we serialize this as XML and give it to the XSLT file and the html is derived from this and is appended to the layer in a page.

The problem with this approach is :

1. The XSLT conversion is occurring on the server side, so the server is responsible for getting the data , running XSLT transform, and append the html generated to the layer div. So, according to me firstly this isn't the server's concern to do so. Secondly for larger applications this might be slower.
2. Debugging isn't possible for XSLT transformation. So, whenever we face problems with data its always a bit of "Trial & Error method".
3. Maintaining it is a bit of an eerie job i.e. styling changes, and other stuff.
4. Adding dynamic values. Like the JavaScript cant be actually very easily used in this. Secondly, we cant use JQuery or any other libraries with this since this is all occurring onto the server.

For now what i have thought about is using Templating - Javascript - JSON combination at the place of XSLT , this will be offloaded to the client and the rendering will take place accordingly.

What could be other ways to implement a Custom CMS ?

What could be the problem with JavaScript based approach ?

Are there any existing frameworks for similar usage ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to build a fully functional CMS, these are usually database driven, I have seen ones built in asp.net and php if that helps?

Comment: @CR41G14 - Yes , sort of that. But onto a smaller scale.